# Requiring proof of dependent eligibility?

Tags: human-resources

My company (> 5K employees globally) for which I've worked for 3+ years, announced that they were going to be verifying that every employee's health care dependent information was correct, as they don't want to be paying health claims on ineligible dependents. Fair enough. I expected to get a letter saying "we show these dependents on your health plan, please verify they still meet the following requirements, sign and return".  Instead, they are requiring that I provide copies (to a third-party auditing firm) of my marriage license, my son's birth certificate, and portions of my tax return showing that I have claimed them as dependents.  I find this extraordinarily invasive and onerous. Is this a standard procedure for large employers?

Comment: Which locale, US I'm guessing?

Comment: Can't say for all companies, but my large company required a marriage license and proof that we shared financial accounts to "prove the marriage is current".  I agree that it's overly invasive. I balked and they eventually agreed to waive it,  but YMMV.

Comment: Why do you find this invasive? Won't you give this information if you were to buy healthcare or insurance plans directly from service providers? It may be just the requirement of the insurance company and not your employer.

Comment: On top of that, put away the tinfoil hat. They are not invasive as they never get the information - that is why there is a third party auditing firm in. Someone will legally check it, your employer never sees the details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is becoming a standard practice. They want to make sure that they are only covering the people they have to.

I don't know that it has anything to do with the size of the company. The employer portion of family coverage can be a thousands of dollars per year for each employee. The company wants to make sure that their portion of premiums and bills isn't higher then it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes companies are definitely verifying dependent information now. My corporation did it as well. It's formality. Although it may seem extreme, healthcare has revolutionized over the past decade. I think the tax returns may be a bit much. Otherwise, I wouldn't let it rattle you. Submit what they are asking you of before your enrollment deadline approaches.

Comment: Most companies want proof that you, and not someone else, is claiming this person as a dependent. My parents claimed my son one year but it didn't affect his eligibility for health insurance through the company I worked for. Each state, country, insurance company, etc. have different criteria for eligibility.